# How to save query results in a local NSArray?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am trying to store the array of objects obtained form PFQuery into a local NSArray. I'm trying to do it inside if (!error) but it does not leave the block, once the block terminates so do the values for it on my array.

```
 @interface InstallersDirectoryTVC ()

 @property (nonatomic,strong) NSArray *installerName;
 @property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *supervisors;


 @end

 //more code goes here
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
      [super viewDidLoad];


   PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"InstallersInfo"];
   [query whereKey:@"supervisor" equalTo:@"yes"];
   [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {

        if (!error) {
            for (PFObject *object in objects) {
                self.supervisors = [objects valueForKey:@"supervisor"];
            }


    }else {
        NSLog(@"Error, %@ %@",error,[error userInfo]);
    }


}];
```

Everything works inside the block, like self.supervisors.count or NSLog, but it doesn't leave the block at all. Could you please tell me how I can get those values?

Thanks!

Comment: hi supervisor is bool type ? and u add object run time in nsmutablearray so please change it.

Comment: Problem is only that, you have `not initialise` your `supervisors` array. `Initialise it` before using it.

Comment: EDIT: The comment above is correct. You have to use NSMutableArray and initialize it before the block. In addition, it looks like for each PFObject in the array you simply assign it to the supervisors variable. You have to append it to the array instead with addObject:

Answer (score 0):

Try following code

```
__weak InstallersDirectoryTVC *weakSelf = self;

    [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {

        if (!error) {
            for (PFObject *object in objects) {
                weakSelf.supervisors = [objects valueForKey:@"supervisor"];
            }


        }else {
            NSLog(@"Error, %@ %@",error,[error userInfo]);
        }


    }];
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use NSMutableArray and initialize it before the block. In addition, it looks like for each PFObject in the array you simply assign it to the supervisors variable. You have to append it to the array instead with addObject:. You also had a typo, you tried to use valueForKey: with the objects array rather than the current object in the iteration.

```
@interface InstallersDirectoryTVC ()

 @property (nonatomic,strong) NSArray *installerName;
 @property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *supervisors;


 @end

 //more code goes here

// initialize the supervisors array in an init method

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
   [super viewDidLoad];   

   PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"InstallersInfo"];
   [query whereKey:@"supervisor" equalTo:@"yes"];
   [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {

        if (!error) {
            for (PFObject *object in objects) {
                [self.supervisors addObject:[object valueForKey:@"supervisor"]];
            }


    }else {
        NSLog(@"Error, %@ %@",error,[error userInfo]);
    }


}];
```